# How can I ignore some elements in <p> with Perl's HTML::TreeBuilder?

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I have to parse this HTML:

```
<p>
<strong>abc:</strong>
asfkjsdg
</p>
```

`$para` contains the value of the element `<p>`. I am using [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder).

$para->as_text

gives me

```
 abc:asfkjsdg
```

How can I get only:

```
 asfkjsdg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
join('', grep { !ref } $para->content_list)
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation of what this syntax means. i am a beginner at perl.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga - it filters out reference types, leaving only the children nodes that are text

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: So you took a Perl job but you do not know any Perl. Interesting. `ref` returns a true value if its argument is a reference. The `grep` thus selects all elements of the content list that are not references.

Comment: To explain the syntax further: any Perl functions substitute $_ or @_ when no argument is given, so !ref really stands for !ref($_); and iterators like grep and map use $_ as the variable that takes each value in turn.  You can find all this in the Perl documentation, e.g. on the command line type perldoc -f ref or perldoc -f grep for details.

Comment: @reinerpost: grep uses $_, but it's not true that any Perl funciton does. Also, only a couple use @_ as a default. You have to check each function to see what its default is. There is no general rule.

Comment: If this code is a sample of <p><strong>a:</strong>b<strong>c:</strong>d</p> You'll need a more intelligent algorithm, because here you'll find you have the value `bd`

Comment: Use the documentation. Type "perldoc -f ref" at the command line, or see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html (and then do the same for the 'grep' function).

Answer (score 0):

```
my @arr=$para->content_list()
my $text= $arr[1] #First is Element second is scalar
print $text; #$text is scalar
```